# Rails 6 Assets precompile fails on heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, webpack

I cannot figure out what is going wrong and have almost seen every SO post regarding this. Deploying Rails 6 app on heroku fails, below is what i get in the build log:

> Compilation failed:
> ModuleNotFoundError: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'module' in '/tmp/build_3cfec286_/node_modules/webpack/lib'
> at /tmp/build_3cfec286_/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compilation.js:925:10
> at /tmp/build_3cfec286_/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModuleFactory.js:401:22
> at /tmp/build_3cfec286_/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModuleFactory.js:130:21

and a few dozen more lines.

Pointers to few files that may help resolve this issue:

1. [github repo](https://github.com/beyond2013/gogopizza/tree/master)
2. [config/webpacker.yml](https://github.com/beyond2013/gogopizza/blob/master/config/webpacker.yml)
3. [config/webpack/environment.js](https://github.com/beyond2013/gogopizza/blob/master/config/webpack/environment.js)
4. [package.json](https://github.com/beyond2013/gogopizza/blob/master/package.json)
5. [Rakefile](https://github.com/beyond2013/gogopizza/blob/master/Rakefile)
6. [babel.config.js](https://github.com/beyond2013/gogopizza/blob/master/babel.config.js)

I can provide more information if needed and would really appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

I think your error come from amazon s3 access_key_id and secret_access_key.

Did you use the `heroku config:set` to set both key ?

Try : `heroku config:set AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=xxx AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=yyy`

[Using AWS S3 to Store Static Assets and File Uploads Heroku documentation](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/s3)

Comment: Yes I have already set up AWS access key id and secret access key, but it doesn't solve the problem